# Suitable Pandas data structure to store heterogenous data (DataFrame (2D) and Series (1D)) using one object?

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures

I am using Pandas for various applications and appreciate it a lot since it makes my life easier.

In most cases, I am working with *homogenous data* and know which [data structure](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/dsintro.html) suits best. So far, I have mostly worked with (multi-indexed) DataFrames and Series parallely, which worked well.

But I got kind of stuck in a current project in which it would be helpfull to handle *heterogenous data* (1D and 2D data) in a common object.

Here's my try using a Panel3D object that hopefully shows what I am looking for:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# dataframes
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 3))
df['concept'] = np.repeat(np.repeat(['A', 'B', 'C'], 2), 1)
df.set_index(['concept'], inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df.columns = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']
df

               C1        C2        C3
concept                              
A       -0.555291 -1.026308 -0.016192
A       -1.759410  0.023008 -0.168303
B       -0.471165  1.160105  0.862017
B       -2.583058  0.595113  0.729354
C        0.706030  1.518058 -1.760176
C       -0.290667 -0.737529 -0.177824

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 3))
df2['concept'] = np.repeat(np.repeat(['A', 'B', 'C'], 2), 1)
df2.set_index(['concept'], inplace=True)
df2.sort_index(inplace=True)
df2.columns = ['C4', 'C5', 'C6']
df2

               C4        C5        C6
concept                              
A        0.784534 -0.590447 -0.661132
A       -0.443176  0.423495 -1.171204
B        1.103484  1.295225  0.112374
B        0.097899 -0.879873  0.213401
C       -1.117570 -0.577390  1.714902
C        1.476986  1.191201  0.973319

# combine dataframes in a panel object (combine homegenous data)
data = {'Item1': df, 'Item2': df2}
my_panel = pd.Panel(data)
my_panel.describe
my_panel.ix['Item2', 'A', 'C4']

concept
A    0.784534
A   -0.443176

# add a series to the dataframe (combine heterogenous data)
s = pd.Series(['gpsol', 125, 'my_simulation_x'],
              index=['solver', 'runtime', 'simulation_name'])
s

solver                       gpsol
runtime                        125
simulation_name    my_simulation_x

# this doesn't work and throws an error as a panel is not the right
# data structure
#  "AssertionError: Length of data and index must match"    
data = {'Item1': df, 'Item2': df2, 'Item3': s}
my_panel = pd.Panel(data)
```

I know it's not intended for Panel3D to have data of different dimensions but if I had a (slicable) data structure that could integrate both 1D and 2D objects it would be great.

Is there something like this in pandas or to I have to use separate pandas objects for this?

If the answer is "No. Pandas is not made for this." it would also be o.k.. I would just like to know if there isn't something suitable for this purpose.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally a DataFrame with a MultiIndex, but your question does not provide enough detail about what your are trying to achieve or what the end result should look like.

Comment: How would you realise this with a MultiIndex? The *1D data* has index levels that are not contained and the *2D data* vice versa. Mustn't all levels be provided?

The end result is an object with " categories/tags of 1D and 2D data e.g. the time series sorted by their type.". Since I am looking for a suitable structure it is hard to describe the structure in advance ;-) But think of it as a Python dictionary with categories as keys and DataFrames/Series as values. I'll also add it to my question..

Comment: The type is just another level to your multiindex columns.  I think you need to show a small example with actual data, otherwise your question is too vague and could get closed.

Comment: I have adapted my question by reproducable code snippets for series/dataframes from the pandas documentation. Does it get clearer now?

Comment: More clear, but it still looks like you have to sets of data with nothing in common, so I'm not sure how you would join them or group them together.  There are many possible answers that could work and which one you choose depends on your needs and objectives.

Comment: Adaption: "...and want to save the Series and DataFrame items in one object which allows a smart subsequent handling/manipulation of the data.".

Comment: Could simply be a nested list, e.g. [[series 1, df1], [series 2, df2], ...].  Or nested dictionary: {'a': {'series': s1, 'dataframe': df1}, ...}. Or a class where you store the variables. Or a...

Comment: "More clear, but it still looks like you have to sets of data with nothing in common, so I'm not sure how you would join them or group them together." This would also be one possible answer: There's is no common pandas data structure for heterogenous data. But I think the question is clear enough and I haven't found a solution on so.com so far.

Comment: I guess it got clear enough for you ;-) Just put your suggestion in an answer if you like!

Comment: These are Python data structures/containers.  This really has nothing to do with Pandas.

Comment: I disagree. This has to do with pandas. My question is if there's a suitable pandas data type to store this data or if I have to use a combination of Python data types together with pandas.

Comment: And I don't see the point why you proposed the question to be closed as it is valuable in my opinion.

Comment: I adapted my quesion one more time "Is there a suitable pandas data structure to hold 1D and 2D data simultaniously or do I have to use python standard data types (dict,..) in addition?" Now it should hopefully be clear.

Comment: I have now reformulated my question completely and provided a detailed example. Could you please remove the delete-flag? I guess it should be specific enough now.

Comment: It's not clear to me what kind of smart access/manipulation are you thinking of. The dataframe and the series you describe look quite unrelated. If the letters in both indexes are expected to match you could use the values of the series as another index level in the dataframe, but I can't see any advantage.

Comment: I meant that I only need a way to access both the DataFrame elements and the Series elements in one object. The letters in both indexes are not meant to match. Practically, both elements are only related on a meta level meaning that the DataFrames are optimisation results and the Series hold parameters that are related to the optimisation run. Thus, it would be handy to have both in one object that can be pickled and later be postprocessed.

Comment: I don't see any point in combining in a single object.  Something like hdf (`df.to_hdf()`) would allow you to store in one file.  This was so confusing....

Comment: I'm sorry if it seems to be confusing and have again reformulated my question completely. Is it getting clearer now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a suitable solution for my case by just adding the (dict of) Series as an attribute to the DataFrame/Panel object.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# dataframes
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 3))
df['concept'] = np.repeat(np.repeat(['A', 'B', 'C'], 2), 1)
df.set_index(['concept'], inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df.columns = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']
df

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 3))
df2['concept'] = np.repeat(np.repeat(['A', 'B', 'C'], 2), 1)
df2.set_index(['concept'], inplace=True)
df2.sort_index(inplace=True)
df2.columns = ['C4', 'C5', 'C6']
df2

# combine dataframes in a panel object (combine homegenous data)
data = {'Item1': df, 'Item2': df2}
opt_results = pd.Panel(data)


# add a series to the dataframe (combine heterogenous data)
opt_params = pd.Series(['gpsol', 125, 'my_simulation_x'],
                       index=['solver', 'runtime', 'simulation_name'])

# this doesn't work and throws an error because of different indexes/dimensions
#data = {'Item1': df, 'Item2': df2, 'Item3': s}
#my_panel = pd.Panel(data)

# but setting the series as an attribute is sufficient for me
opt_results.info = opt_params
opt_results.info
solver                       gpsol
runtime                        125
simulation_name    my_simulation_x
dtype: object

opt_results.ix['Item2', 'A', 'C4']
concept
A   -0.660582
A   -1.174828
Name: C4, dtype: float64
```

Maybe it was a bit confusing because the answer was too obvious..